# How do I split a cube into two parts using the shape of a sphere?

Tags: mesh

I'm interesting in creating 3D sculptures that have been dissected and split apart using various shapes.
So in this question... how do I split a cube into two parts using the shape of a sphere to cut with?
thanks!

Comment: One way is to use the boolean modifier and subtract the sphere. Than you duplicate the cube and change the boolean operation to intersection. Then you can apply the boolean on both cubes and delete the sphere and you will have two parts of the cube perfectly split in the shape of the sphere.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking! Just wondered if I was missing a quicker solution.

Answer (score 1):

Some variation on this may give you cleaner topology than a Boolean without too much work. The cube in the background is to snap to, the snap is set to 'Vertex' and 'Active', and the Pivot is set to 'Active Element'.

[image]

1. Under <kbd>O</kbd> Proportional Editing / 'Spherical'. Connected', drag the center-point of a grid out to the desired radius. (Then switch off Proportional Editing)
2. With all verts selected, and a handy one active, <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> extrude the faces out, snapping  a reference, as shown..
3. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> flatten the end to the active vertex.
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate the spherical surface, and repeat steps 2 and 3 at the opposite end.

(There may be <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> some normals-correction to do, to make sure faces are all the right-side-out)